# converting the psftp command written on windows on to linux in python

Tags: python, operating-system, sftp

I am working on python, actually i am trying to connect to sftp and get some files after connecting.

The process which i followed on **windows** is below

```
import os

psftpCmd='psftp sftp.example.com -l user -pw pass -b client_configurations\lifebridge.scr -batch'

os.system(psftpCmd)
```

The code in lifebrige.scr is

```
cd lifebridge
lcd feeds\lifebridge
get jobs.xml
bye
```

So i am able to fetch the file successfully i want to do the same process on linux(fedora) machine and i tried the following

```
import os

psftpCmd='psftp sftp.example.com -l user -pw pass -b client_configurations\lifebridge.scr -batch'
os.system(psftpCmd)
```

**Result**:

```
sh: psftp: command not found
```

Here i can expect that psftp is putty command so need to do something else on linux fro the same, Can anyone let me now how to write the same command in linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux, the command is sftp.

Comment: Thanks for reply and i am getting the same result usage: sftp [-1246Cpqrv] [-B buffer_size] [-b batchfile] [-c cipher]
          [-D sftp_server_path] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
          [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-R num_requests] [-S program]
          [-s subsystem | sftp_server] host
       sftp [user@]host[:file ...]
       sftp [user@]host[:dir[/]]
       sftp -b batchfile [user@]host

Comment: It looks like sftp does not use the same parameters as psftp. You will need to remove -l, and replace the hostname with user@sftp.example.com.

However, you will run into problems with the password. For some possible solutions see http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/36002-how-give-passwd-along-sftp.html